# PHP DOMDocument: How to pull two(2) values from a Webpage when one value doesnt have an ID value

Tags: php, domdocument

I would like to pull two values from a web document. The values are **api_key** and **authenticity_token**. I have written a function but the problem is it only pulls out the api_key. Can someone help me with the other piece of this function that will enable me to pull out the authenticity_token, THANKS:

Here’s my code for my function:

```
    <?php 
class apiKey{
    public $apikey;
    public $authenticity_token;


     function getApiKey(){
        //Get api_key and pass it in
        $apikey = null;
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $semcatStartUrl = 'https://entryform.semcat.net/1800stonewall';
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc->loadHTMLFile("$semcatStartUrl");
        libxml_clear_errors();
        $apikey = $doc->getElementById('api_key')->getAttribute('value');
        return $apikey;

    }

    function getAuthenticityToken(){
        //My guesstimate this doesn’t work because the form hasn’t been /               //submitted yet
        $authenticity_token = $_POST['authenticity_token'];
        return $authenticity_token;
    }

}


?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

The authenticity token is contained in this element:

```
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="..." />
```

Unfortunately, as you can see, this element has no ID attribute and therefore getting at it will be slightly more complicated.

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$input = $xpath->query("input[@name=authenticity_token]")->item(0)->getAttribute("value");
```

Ideally you'll want some error checking in there to make sure the element exists, but this code should work fine... provided it is in the same place as your existing "get API key" function, because it uses `$doc`.

Comment: Made some slight changes I will post the entire working code in an answer. Thanks for the help it put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete working code:

```
<?php 
class apiKey{
    public $apikey;
    public $authenticity_token;


     function getApiKey(){
        //Get api_key and pass it in
        $apikey = null;
        $authenticity_token = null;
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $semcatStartUrl = 'https://entryform.semcat.net/1800stonewall';
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc->loadHTMLFile("$semcatStartUrl");
        libxml_clear_errors();
        $apikey = $doc->getElementById('api_key')->getAttribute('value');

        //Original 2 Lines
        //$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
        //$input = $xpath->query("input[@name=authenticity_token]")->item(0)->getAttribute("value");

            //Modified 2 Lines and added 2 Lines
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);    
        $input = $xpath->query("//input[@name='authenticity_token']"); 
        $authenticity_token = $input->item(0)->getAttribute('value');
        $this->authenticity_token = $authenticity_token;

        return $apikey;

    }

    function getAuthenticityToken(){

                return $this->authenticity_token;
    }

}


?>
```

Works like a great programmer! Thanks for the Help. It really help point me in the right direction which after doing a little research and testing I was able to make some slight changes to your code to get it successfully working, error free.